# Fast comparing array to the number

Tags: c++, performance

I have an array of ints and I want to count how many `not 1` numbers is there:

```
int* t = new int[50];
int counter = 1;
for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
    t[i] = i % 10;
    if((memcmp((void*)t[i], (void*)1, 4) != 0)){
        counter++;
    }
}
```

But I get `adress violation`. How to make it work... work fast. Do you know faster solution, not standard one. Please no `t[i]==1`.

EDIT:
Because I use array of size `362856427` in the program and I wanted to make it simple.

Comment: um... `if(t[i]!=1)`. Using `memcmp` here is bizarre.

Comment: What makes you think "that solution" (`t[i] == 1`) is not the fastest possible one?

Comment: This "not that solution" was about t[i]==1 . I do not if it is fastest i need fastest please no chat here.

Comment: You're going to have to explain why you're being weird with the restrictions. Are there other restrictions? Is this a dare?

Comment: Also the fastest solution is to remove the `if` and write `counter = 5;` at the end of the loop.

Comment: You're making silly assumptions. `==` is a fast as it gets. Try to make it correct first...

Comment: This misuse of `memcmp` is not going to be faster than the obvious, and simple, comparison. Please profile both versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: do it the obvious way, and make sure your compiler optimizes it.

---

It's hard to reason about performance without a full, reproducible program example.  So let's start with a straightforward implementation:

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

std::array<int, 362856427> a = {};

int main()
{
    a[500] = 1;
    a[5000] = 1;
    a[50000] = 1;
    a[500000] = 1;

    auto counter = 0u;
    for (auto i = 0u; i < a.size(); ++i) {
    if (a[i] != 1)
        ++counter;
    }

    return counter != 362856423;
}
```

Timing this, I got 1.79 seconds of user time.  Then I realised my mistake, and added `-O3` to my compilation command.  That's better:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -g -Wall -Wextra -O3  16385733.cpp -o 16385733
time ./16385733 
0.07user 0.08system 0:00.16elapsed 98%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 2212maxresident)k
```

We can attempt to simplify the loop, but this makes no measurable difference (the optimizer already beat us to this one):

```
for (auto i = 0u;  i < a.size();  ++i)
    counter += a[i] != 1;
```

Another option is to make the code clearer, by using a standard algorithm:

```
auto counter = a.size() - std::count(a.begin(), a.end(), 1);
```

This consistently takes 50% longer than the obvious loop.

If your input array was substantially larger, you might be able to gain by parallelizing the computation like this:

```
     auto counter = 0ul;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:counter)
    for (auto i = 0ul;  i < a.size();  ++i)
        counter += a[i] != 1;
```

My benchmarking showed this as being as slow as the standard algorithm when the array size is 362856427, and no faster when it's increased to 3628564270.

There are a few ways to re-write in equivalent form:

```
    for (auto i: a)
        counter += i != 1;
```

```
    for (auto p = a.data();  p < end;  ++p)
        counter += *p != 1;
```

All these exhibit similar performance, and aren't improved with OpenMP.

So the short answer is

- do it the obvious way
- make sure your compiler is optimizing, and
- benchmark your alternatives.

Answer (score 5):

Why not do this:

```
int *t = new int[50];
int counter = 0; // <-- Shouldn't it be "0" at the beginning?
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  if (t[i] != 1) {
    counter++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are typecasting 1 onto the address.  That will imply that you are comparing at the address 1 and not against 1.  Your solution will be to create `int one = 1;` and then, put `&one` in place of `(void*)1`.

Comment: @RobertKilar, A-It will end... B-it won't end any faster than that!

Comment: I noticed another issue.  You are using the pointer to t[i].  It should change to (void*)(t+i).  Also, you counter should be initialized to 0.

Comment: I just ran your code with my changes on my Linux laptop.  It ran fine with your suggested size of array.

Answer (score 0):

In C++1x you can use `std::count`:

```
const int N = 50;
int* t = new int[N];
int counter = N - std::count(t, t+N, 1);
```